# hostname lookups stop working on Debian install

Tags: debian, hostname

I just installed Debian, and I'm experiencing the peculiar problem that hostname lookups inevitably stop working after I've been logged in.  I can continue to ping IP addresses after this happens, and I can even surf the web by pasting IP addresses into the URL bar on Firefox.  I tried installing resolvconf (not sure if this is normal, but somehow it wasn't installed by default), but that hasn't fixed the problem.  The amount of time it takes for hostname lookups to stop working varies; sometimes it happens within a minute of logging on to my computer and sometimes it works for upwards of half an hour.  This problem doesn't happen on any other computer on the network and it didn't happen on this PC until I installed debian.  Has anybody ever seen any problems like this?

from /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2
nameserver 75.75.75.75
search hsd1.ca.comcast.net
```

from /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   invincible

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What happens when you run an [`nslookup <host> <nserver>`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup) on each of your name servers before and after the issue?

Comment: Could be a network driver issue I suppose. What does `lspci` (or `lsusb` if it is USB) say your network adapter is - the make and model?